# Java getMethods() with respect to inheritance hirarchy

Tags: java, sorting, reflection

What I eventually want to do is to invoke all methods that have some annotation in a way such that:

1. Overridden methods will be invoked only once.
2. In case the class of the object is `B`, and it inherits from `A` which inherits from `Object`, I want the methods defined in `Object` with that annotation to be invoked first, then the methods in `A`, and then the methods in `B`.

Is there a way to get the methods sorted in such way?

Comment: What code have you attempted so far?

Comment: @markspace I was wondering if there is a quick way to do this. Right now, I use a stack to keep the methods and use getSuperClass() until I reach Object.

Comment: What do you mean by "invoked only once"?

Comment: @aran If A defines foo and B overrides foo, only B's foo will be invoked.

Comment: so make A extend B, and its super will call B on the override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that sorts the `Method` objects according to the class that declared them:

```
public static class MethodInheritanceComparator implements Comparator<Method> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Method m1, Method m2) {
        Class<?> class1 = m1.getDeclaringClass();
        Class<?> class2 = m2.getDeclaringClass();

        if (class1.equals(class2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (class1.isAssignableFrom(class2)) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (class2.isAssignableFrom(class1)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then use it to sort the `Method` objects you have. E.g.:

```java
Method[] methods = // All the relevant methods...
Arrays.sort(methods, new MethodInheritanceComparator());
```

Note that `Class#getMethods` only returns one `Method` object in the case of an overridden method, so your first requirement is fulfilled "out of the box".

Comment: From [javadoc of compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-),
*Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.*
It seems the implementation does not fulfill this requirement? Suppose we have class `Parent`, `Child` extends `Parent` and `String`, 
`compare(Parent, String) == 0` but `sgn(compare(Parent, Child)) != sgn(compare(String, Child))`.
Please correct me if I miss anything.